# WPF button binding to a property Convertback IMultiValueConverter does not update value

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, converters, multibinding

I have a binding from a toggle button hooked up in code behind.
I want to bind the isChecked state from one button to 4 video controls to toggle the mute function. I am using multibinding to bind the toggle button to 4 different controls. My problem is using breakpoints i can see everything is triggered right up to the property mute property on each object, but the property "value" parameter never gets updated. It stays at the default setting when the controls are instantiated.

So first i create the bindings in code behind

```
        IMultiValueConverter converter = new EmptyMultiValueConverter();
        MultiBinding myMultiBinding = new MultiBinding();
        myMultiBinding.Converter = converter;
        myMultiBinding.UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.Default;
        myMultiBinding.Mode = BindingMode.OneWayToSource;      
        myMultiBinding.NotifyOnSourceUpdated = true;  



        for (int i = 1; i < _maxNumberofPlayers; i++)
        {
            VideoPlayer player = new VideoPlayer()
            {
                Mute = false
            };

          myMultiBinding.Bindings.Add(new Binding("Mute") { Source = player 
         });

        }


     btnMuteToggle.SetBinding(SimpleButton.IsCheckedProperty, myMultiBinding);
```

This all seems to work because when i click on the button i can see in the multivalue converter the correct isChecked button status arrives at the breakpoints, at ConvertBack below i can confirm the value is the correct bool that reflects the toggle button state.

```
public class EmptyMultiValueConverter : IMultiValueConverter
{
    #region IMultiValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object 
    parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        // gets from the object source
        return (bool)values[0];
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object 
   parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {

        return new Object[] {value,value,value,value};
    }

    #endregion
}
```

At this point i can confirm it hits the Mute property, and triggers the SET 4 times, but as i trace through it the value parameter remains at the previously set value, and does not update to reflect the value passed to it via ConvertBack

```
   // mute property in the media player user control
    public bool Mute
    {
        get { return  _media.IsMuted; }
        set
        {       
            if (_media.IsMuted == value)
                return;
            else
            {
                _media.IsMuted = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("Mute");
            }

        }
    }
```

Can anyone help please.
Have been tearing my hair out for 3 days.

It seemed to me using multibinding is an efficient way to hook up 4 seperat controls players and bind them to one button click.

Comment: i ve read it 3 times and i dont undestand what you are trying to do in gerneral..

Comment: Im trying to get multibindings to work to click one toggle button and use the ischecked (true or false) status to bind to 4 different media player controls and toggle the mute status property on those controls.

Comment: if you have 4 media controls and want all them to mute with one button there is no need for multibinding just bind all of them to the button directly without the converter

Comment: I tried that, in code behind, by creating 4 individual binding instances to the same toggle button. but the only one that functioned was the last one bound. Binding one button to one video control in code behind works perfectly otherwise.

Comment: But this should work and is the correct thing to do in your case. Why are you even trying to work out XAML elements in code?
its much easier to actually use XAML as it was intended to...

Comment: The video controls are instantiated dynamically  in code behind as required and can vary in number from 1 to 4 depending on various parameters. Most of the time it will be 4 but can vary. Hence i cant bind in xaml when i dont even know how many controls will exist at run time.

Comment: Makes sense! Still you are able to bind all of these controls to one and the same togglebutton. You do not need multibinding here and you do not need the Converter. If all this is driving you crazy you can still use a icommand to mute and unmute them when the togglebutton is pushed. This would also have the adventage of you beeing able to resotre the previous state they were in. Example: All muted but one->Click-> All Muted-> Click -> all unmuted -> 4 mediaplayers making sound istead of only the one that was previously

Comment: I will try the original binding option you suggest, again, failing that i will look at the icommand option and report back. I am very disappointed  that i cant work out why this multibinding does not work. it seemed like an elegant solution.

Comment: Are you using the MVVM pattern or are you doing everything event based?

Comment: Its all in code behind in the main window class in methods called when the number of required players is known. the IMultiValueConverter is a separate class in the same project.

Comment: okay in this case i recommand learning MVVM but this is over the top of this question...instead of using an icommand you can use a click event to set the players muted
Click->`If((sender as ToggleButton).IsChecked){Store current Condition and mute all}else{->restore previous condition}`

Comment: I will try all those options. thanks.

Comment: Did you try specifying the Binding mode in your individual bindings?

Answer (score 0):

well I have tried several options again and none of them work except code in a click button event

Multibinding just does not work at all.
I can see in break points that the Mute property is being called 4 times for 4 controls but the value parameter is never updated to the new property value.

I also tried binding the one button to 4 different controls

```
foreach(Player player in lsPlayers)
{
    btnMuteToggle.SetBinding(SimpleButton.IsCheckedProperty, new Binding("Mute")
       {
         Source = player,
         UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged,
         Mode = BindingMode.OneWayToSource
        });
}
```

This just results in one player object mute property being called.
You cant bind more than one control to the same button.
It just does not work.

so I just called the 4 objects in a click event.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that in this case you may want to bind those 4 properties to the mute property individually and make sure each is set Mode to TwoWay. But if MultiValueConverter supports it, I can't particularly argue with your approach.

It appears that you have not made a Dependency Property for Mute. this is vital to the WPF Binding Workflow and tends to scale easier than NotifyPropertyChanged as NotifyPropertyChanged can tend towards requiring you to manage more. A DependencyProperty will abstract away both sending and receiving the updates to your property and the Xaml editor support for it is better.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/how-to-implement-a-dependency-property

I find WPF Binding to be nice in theory, but still requires a lot more leg work than it needs to. Have a function. I add it to all of my WPF viewmodels and controls.

```
/// <summary>
/// simplify wpf binding
/// </summary>
/// <param name="name"></param>
/// <param name="type"></param>
/// <param name="preferNull">Fair Warning. if you create an instance, you will have also created a singleton of this property for all instances of this class. </param>
/// <returns></returns>
private static DependencyProperty AddDp(string name, Type type, bool preferNull = true)
{
    return DependencyProperty.Register(name, type, typeof(Setting),
        new PropertyMetadata((!preferNull || type.IsValueType) ? Activator.CreateInstance(type) : null));
}
```

Just inherit from DependencyObject and you can make mute look more like this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty MuteDp = AddDp(nameof(Mute), typeof(bool));
public bool Mute
{
    get => (bool)GetValue(MuteDp);
    set { if(value != Mute) SetValue(MuteDp, value); }
}
```

But Be Warned!
Sometimes WPF Binding to a Dependency Property updates the Dependency Property's internal values without entering the setter of its corresponding property! This was the case on a MultiValueBinding I used.
meaning it may never touch the Mute::Set accessor. This can be pretty problematic, to counter this issue you can use the various callbacks available to a DependencyObject!

```
private static DependencyProperty AddDp(string name, Type type, bool preferNull = true)
{
    var dp = DependencyProperty.Register(name, type, typeof(Setting),
        new PropertyMetadata(
            (!preferNull || type.IsValueType) ? Activator.CreateInstance(type) : null
            ,new PropertyChangedCallback((dobj, dpe)=>
            {
                //after property changed.
                //forcing usage of set accessor
                ((MuteContainerObj)dobj).Value = ((strong text)dobj).Value;
                //or forcibly use an update function
                ((MuteContainerObj)dobj).MuteUpdated();
            }),new CoerceValueCallback((dobj, o)=> {
                //before property changed
                return o;
            })), new ValidateValueCallback((o)=> {
                //before property change events
                return true;
            }));
    return dp;
        
}
```